# HTC Vive & SteamVR freezes Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive, openvr

I have the SteamVR plugin installed in Unity correctly but at random points in time or for some reason when I'm doing animations, the Unity Editor freezes. This doesn't happen for any non-vr projects and if I'm in Play mode when it freezes, I'm still able to play the game in VR with all scripts working, so it's just the Editor itself that's freezing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.